# How can I analyze a nodejs heap dump?

Tags: node.js, heap-dump, node-heapdump

I have a memory leak in my nodejs express server. I have already generated the heap dump, however it is almost 250mb. When I try to load it into Chrome (Dev tools -> Memory -> Load), Chrome will attempt to load the file but after about 60 seconds the dev tools crash. The CPU usage for Chrome spikes to 200%+ during this process, so I assume the heap is too large for Chrome to handle. When I attempt the same process in other browsers (Firefox & Edge), the memory tab won't even let me select the file, which is a `.heapsnapshot`. I am using a brand new Apple M2 max (64gb mem), so compute power shouldn't be an issue.

Is there any other tool or way to analyze a heap snapshot? Third-party tools are fine, even if paid.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [memlab](https://facebook.github.io/memlab/). You can analyze a full directory of dumps by writing e.g. `memlab analyze unbound-shape --snapshot-dir ./`